# How can you access the function from another translation unit without including any files?

Tags: c++, static-functions

I was reading about static functions and it was said that if the function is static then you can use it only in the same file. After testing it, I realized it is not true because if you include the file with a static function you can still use that function in another file. Then I read a clarification that you can actually use static function only in the same translation unit. Ok, that makes sense because it means .cpp + includes, but even if the function is not static, you will still not be able to use it unless you include the file. So how is it even possible to access a function from another translation unit in the first place without including anything, what is the point of static functions?

Main.cpp

```
#include "Staticf.h"

void main()
{
  visible();
}
```

Staticf.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

static void visible()
{
  cout << "Static function is visible\n";
}
```

This compiles alright. If I make that function non-static and remove #include "Staticf.h" I will not be able to use it in Main anyways. So why are static functions needed if you can't access non-static as well?

Comment: If you include something, the included file and the file that includes it are the same file.

Comment: Yes, I know that, that was not the question

Comment: What is the point of calling someone that you don't know their address, name and phone number?

Comment: `#include <iostream>
using namespace std`; is the worst path you can take on in a header file.

Comment: FWIW, this is a hold over from C.  In C++ if you want to hide a function you can use a namespace.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access non-static functions from other translation units.  You just need a forward declaration:

**somemodule.cpp**

```
void func()
{
  // details
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
void func();

int main()
{
  func();
}
```

It is, of course, a best practice to put the forward declaration in a header file.

**So what use are static functions?**

In modern C++, they actually aren't much use.  `static` is a feature C++ inherited from C.  In C, declaring a helper function `static` is actually pretty useful because C doesn't have namespaces.  You can use `static` to eliminate the chance of name collisions between your private helper functions and the private helper functions in other translation units.  In C++, it's generally preferred to wrap your private helpers in a class or anonymous namespace.

Comment: You could mention OOP for your C++ section =)

Comment: Thanks, I tested it and this answered my question. I didn't think about forward declaration

Answer (score 1):

If the function is static (as if free static function), you cannot access it from another translation unit.

Remove the `static`, and if you can't include a header (you probably can though... change the former static function's header), add a prototype in the file.